# I have a four column word doc page in landscape. I want to cut and paste that into a portrait doc and display the text at 90 degrees

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a four column word doc page in landscape. I want to cut and paste that into a portrait doc and display the text at 90 degrees with all four columns in tact. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you just meaning you want to rotate your landscape page to portrait?

Answer (score 0):

Page orientation in word is by section.

- Go to the spot in your "portrait doc" where you wish to place your landscape page.
- Select Page Layout -->Breaks --> "Section Break>Next Page"
- Repeat: Select Page Layout -->Breaks --> "Section Break>Next Page"
- This should leave you with a blank page in portrait mode.  Put your cursor on it.
- Select Page Layout --> Orientation --> Landscape
- Paste in your four columns from the other document